# Service connection creation operation failed

Tags: azure-devops, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a release pipeline on Azure DevOps but I got this error message when I select and authorize Azure subcription:

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

"Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Ensure that the user has permissions to create an Azure Active Directory Application."

What specific permission do I need on Azure AD? Owner? or in a Azure DevOps?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an administrator role？

Comment: Is it your own subscritpion? If yes, do you use the same account for Azure DevOps and Azure? You need `User Access Adminsitrator` role - please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin)

Comment: @CarlZhao On DevOps I’m administrator but on Azure I’m contributor over specific resource groups. Over subscription, anything

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej It's subscription from another organization. Thanks

Comment: @Sergio  Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio Not get your latest information, is Carl Zhao's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: thanks @CarlZhao it's solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem on my side.

changing `Users can register applications` to `Yes` will fix this issue.

Go to azure portal->click Azure Active Direcotory->User settings

[image]